# Creating an sql table based off of a variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a database that includes 3 primary tables:

Users, Assignments, Groups

With other potential tables that relate to the table 'Groups'. These potential tables are meant to be tables which are named based on the key variable in the "Groups" table. eg if the Groups table has an entry with groupName = "Group_One", I want to create a table called "Group_One" and then store the usernames of other users into that table. As don't see a practical way to store multiple usernames in one row of the 'Groups' table.

Here is the code I am testing to try and implement this:

```
import sqlite3

def Database_Setup():
    Cur.executescript(
                        """
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
                        (
                        username text,
                        password text,
                        clearance int,
                        classes int
                        );
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUPS 
                        (
                        groupName text
                        teacher text,
                        teachingAssistant text
                        users
                        );
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ASSIGNMENTS
                        (
                        assignmentID int,
                        assignmentName text,
                        assignmentInfo text,
                        dueDate date,
                        setDate date,
                        completedAmount int
                        )
                        """
                        )
def Potential_Solution():
    Group_Name = "Group1"
    List_Of_Users = ["User1","User2","User3"]
    Cur.execute("""
                      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}
                      (
                      username text,
                      randomVar text
                      )
                      """.format(Group_Name))
                      # This part works fine ^^
    for User in List_Of_Users:
        Cur.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE ? values (?,'Some_Var')",(Group_Name,User))

def Main():
    Database_Setup()
    Potential_Solution()
    Cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Group1")
    print(Cur.fetchall())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Conn = sqlite3.connect("FOO_DB.db")
    Cur = Conn.cursor()
    Main()
```

However when I execute this, I run into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/Py_Proj/DB LIST vs new db example.py", line 53, in <module>
    Main()
  File "E:/Python/Py_Proj/DB LIST vs new db example.py", line 46, in Main
    Potential_Solution()
  File "E:/Python/Py_Proj/DB LIST vs new db example.py", line 42, in Potential_Solution
    Cur.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE ? values (?,Some_Var)",(Group_Name,User))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "TABLE": syntax error
```

is there a practical way to do what I am trying to achieve? Or should I resort to another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I tried the following , 
you have to remove TABLE keyword use positional formatting 
Cur.execute("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES('{1}', 'SomeVar')".format(Group_Name,User )
                )

import sqlite3

def Database_Setup():
    Cur.executescript(
                        """
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
                        (
                        username text,
                        password text,
                        clearance int,
                        classes int
                        );
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUPS 
                        (
                        groupName text
                        teacher text,
                        teachingAssistant text
                        users
                        );
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ASSIGNMENTS
                        (
                        assignmentID int,
                        assignmentName text,
                        assignmentInfo text,
                        dueDate date,
                        setDate date,
                        completedAmount int
                        )
                        """
                        )
def Potential_Solution():
    Group_Name = "Group1"
    List_Of_Users = ["User1","User2","User3"]
    Cur.execute("""
                      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}
                      (
                      username text,
                      randomVar text
                      )
                      """.format(Group_Name))
    for User in List_Of_Users:
        Cur.execute("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES('{1}', 'SomeVar')".format(Group_Name,User )
                    )





def Main():
    Database_Setup()
    Potential_Solution()
    Cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Group1")
    print(Cur.fetchall())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Conn = sqlite3.connect("FOO_DB.db")
    Cur = Conn.cursor()
    Main()
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Not having the table part was probably the main issue

Comment: However do you know of any better way to do this? or would this be considered the best way?

Comment: you can use SQLAlchemy for the ORM mapping , refer to the link here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html. If your schema is not a complex one you can stick on to your solution